# Android Jetpack Navigation component and BottomAppBar menu interaction

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-architecture-components, android-navigation, android-jetpack

I am trying to implement `Navigation` inside my project while having `Top App Bar` and `Bottom App Bar` in my main activity.

Here are the steps I've made.

In my activity layout

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
       <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
           <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar/>
       </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

  <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/navigation_graph" />

<android.support.design.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar/>
```

I have 2 fragments, let's say `FragmentStart` and `FragmentToGoTo` so in my navigation graph I have

```
<navigation
    android:id="@+id/navigation_graph.xml"
    app:startDestination="@id/fragmentStart">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragmentStart"
        android:name="com.FragmentStart">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/goToFragment"
            app:destination="@id/fragmentToGoTo" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragmentToGoTo"
        android:name="com.FragmentToGoTo"
        />
</navigation>
```

The `Bottom App Bar` menu has the item:

```
 <item
        android:id="@id/fragmentToGoTo"
        android:title="Title"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
```

Then on my activity

```
val navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.navigation_fragment)
myBottomBar.replaceMenu(R.menu.menu_with_nav_item)

myBottomBar.setupWithNavController(navController)
//or I've also tried
//NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(myBottomBar, navController, null)
```

What happens is that when clicking on the menu item, the navigation does not trigger and from what I've read, if the menu entry has the same id as the fragment in navigation graph, it should work directly.
If I add `OnMenuItemClickListener` I can do on menu press do `findNavController(R.id.navigation_fragment).navigate(R.id.fragmentToGoTo)` and it works. I just would have liked an automatic way for this since it should be available.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Currently it is not possible
https://twitter.com/ianhlake/status/1022488370725810178
I filled a feature request:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/111843776

Answer (score 1):

Hy

I'm new to Kotlin, but I had the same issue.

You also have to tie your `menu` with your `navController` with:

```kotlin
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
  val navController = findNavController(R.id.fragmentContainer)
  return item.onNavDestinationSelected(navController) ||
    super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
}
```

Just paste these code in your `MainActivity.kt`.

I've got the code from the Android docs: https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#Tie-navdrawer